# Case When Variable Is null then is null

Tags: oracle, plsql

In my sql query I'm having this where condition:

```
WHERE 
  parentID = prj.parent_id
  and mandator_fk = mandator_id
```

The variable `parentID` is null as default.

If this variable is null the `WHERE` condition should be `parentID is null` and not like in the query above (`parentID = prj.parent_id`). If this variable is filled the `WHERE` condition should be `parentID = prj.parent_id`.

How can I perform this with only one sql query?

---

EDIT: its inside a function, thats why I would have only one sql query for this.

This is not working I know that, but this is like what I need:

```
WHERE 
   CASE 
      WHEN parentID is null THEN parentID is null
   ELSE
     parentID = prj.parent_ID
   END
and mandator_fk = mandator_id
```

TIA
frgtv10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems you want to join on nulls, so you'll need to convert them first.  Try this:

```
where
NVL(parentId, 0) = NVL(prj.parent_id, 0)
and ...
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if `NVL()` function is surgable, so here is another way to write the condition:

```
WHERE 
    ( parentID = prj.parent_id 
   OR parentID IS NULL AND prj.parent_id IS NULL
    )
  AND mandator_fk = mandator_id
```